# Use standard inputs with angular material checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-material

Is there a way to us the normal input checkbox, for .NET forms? Or do I have to create my own directive/modify the material one to get this to work.

```
<md-checkbox ng-checked="$ctrl.checked = !$ctrl.checked">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />
</md-checkbox>
```

Obviously I could add the same ng-checked attribute to the input, however i feel this is a little unnecessary, I would have assumed a simple name attribute would automatically add in a hidden checkbox with a truthy value and automatically toggle the nested checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('mainController', function() {});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <md-switch ng-model="switch" aria-label="Switch 1">
      Set/Unset checkbox
    </md-switch>
    <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="switch">
    Of course the checkbox would normally be hidden
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I agree with you, it would be useful to have this automatically in Angular Material

Comment: This doesn't use checkbox though, it's two different fields for a simple solution